# How do I display the date but not the author?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I want articles to show *Submitted on* without showing *Submitted by*. The checkbox on *Display settings* toggles both, not only one of them.
[Control/modify display settings (author and date) on posts](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/controlmodify-display-settings-author-and-date-information-on-posts) explains how to do it in Drupal 7.

How should I achieve it in Drupal 8, for example with the *Bartik* theme?

Comment: You probably should create a sub-theme of Bartik first to simply edit the templates. You also could create a pseudo field from a custom module.

Comment: do you have a custom module or theme in your project?

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to edit the node.html.twig template used from the theme. For example, the Bartik theme uses a [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21bartik%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.9.x) template containing the following code. (I omitted the documentation comment at the beginning of the file.)

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'node',
    'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
    node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
    node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
    not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    'clearfix',
  ]
%}
{{ attach_library('bartik/classy.node') }}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  <header>
    {{ title_prefix }}
      {% if label and not page %}
      <h2{{ title_attributes.addClass('node__title') }}>
        <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
      </h2>
    {% endif %}
    {{ title_suffix }}
    {% if display_submitted %}
      <div class="node__meta">
        {{ author_picture }}
        <span{{ author_attributes }}>
          {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
        </span>
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </header>
  <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content', 'clearfix') }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
</article>
```

The line printing the name of the user who created the node and when it was posted is the following one.

```
{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
```

It's enough to change it and remove the part printing the username. In the case of the Bartik theme, the node.html.twig content will become the following one.

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'node',
    'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
    node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
    node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
    not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    'clearfix',
  ]
%}
{{ attach_library('bartik/classy.node') }}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  <header>
    {{ title_prefix }}
      {% if label and not page %}
      <h2{{ title_attributes.addClass('node__title') }}>
        <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
      </h2>
    {% endif %}
    {{ title_suffix }}
    {% if display_submitted %}
      <div class="node__meta">
        {{ author_picture }}
        <span{{ author_attributes }}>
          {% trans %}Submitted on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
        </span>
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </header>
  <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content', 'clearfix') }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
</article>
```

For a different theme, it's enough searching the line of the node.html.twig template containing `{{ author_name }}` and remove it. Clearly, also the sentence containing `{{ author_name }}` needs to be changed to make it grammatical. (*Submitted by on `{{ date }}`* would not be grammatically correct.)

As general suggestion, never change a template file used from a Drupal core theme or a third-party theme. Rather, create a sub-theme using that theme as parent theme, and add the template files you need to change.